# Cors policy blocking in jquery AJAX API calls on jersey backend

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, jersey, cors

I have developed a webapp using jersey and jsp. all jersey API calls are working as except in postman but when i make ajax call in jsp it getting an error as shown below

[image]

I added cors filter in my back end in my CORSFilter.java

```
package com.telusko.demorest.Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
            ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        System.out.println("jhjhjhbjh");
    }
}
```

here is my front end Ajax call

```
 var $url="http://localhost:8080/demorest/webapi/aliens/alien/103";

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }, //add this line
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',                
        success: function (Data) {return false;
    }
```

this is my back end method

```
@Path("aliens")
public class AlienController {

    AlienRepository repo=new AlienRepository();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<AlienModel> getaliens() {
        return repo.getAliens();
    }
}
```

and added these lines to web.xml too

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.telusko.demorest.CORSFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

is there anything i have to implement in my front end 
any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

i just realized that i have added a access control header in my front end with the ajax call so that was the issue when i removed the

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
```

from my front end ajax call it works perfectly:)